# Error when scrolling in selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scroll to the bottom of the page, as I usually do. But on this website it seems not to work. It's one of those where you need to scroll to the bottom in order to load new links.

This is the command I am using:

```py
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

The error I am getting is:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/somePathTo/someProgram.py", line 12, in <module>
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=72.0.3626.69 (3c16f8a135abc0d4da2dff33804db79b849a7c38),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.3 x86_64)
```

Any other scroll does not work as well, something is wrong with the JS script... 
I don't know what element is null and therefore can't have the 'offsetTop' property... maybe I should identify some element that can have that property, but I don't know much more about JS than this script

EDIT:
I did solve my specific problem with this code

```py
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', target)
```

where target is an element to the bottom. However, I would like to know what the issue is with the JS code.

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: I would like to successfully scroll to the bottom of the page. Does that clarify?

Comment: Find an element at the bottom of the page (like footer element) and the use `driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_goes_here").location_once_scrolled_into_view`. This will scroll to that footer element.

Comment: Can you share website link?

Comment: yes supputuri, I managed to do it like that

Comment: Sounds like the window hasn't loaded. It is getting the document offset, but saying that document is null. Have you added waits to make sure that the page has loaded before scrolling?

Comment: @Asyranok I kept trying in the shell after running the script so it wasn't that!